# Pre populating Select2 using AJAX - "No Results Found"

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-select2, select2-rails

I've been following this sample guide (http://rails-select2-example.herokuapp.com/) to create a select2 drop down to search for countries from my database.

However the select box always comes back empty with "No Results Found". Why wont it pick up the values from js/ajax?

View (new.html.erb)

```
          <select class="form-control" id="country_select">
          </select>
```

Controller (Searches_controller.rb)

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
before_action :require_user
respond_to :html, :json

    def new
        @countries = Country.all
        respond_with @countries
    end
end
```

Javascript

```
  $('#country_select').select2({
    theme: "bootstrap",
    ajax: {
      url: "<%= user_searches_path(format: 'json') %>",
      dataType: "json",
      results: function(data, page) {
        return { results: $.map( data, function(country, i) { 
          return { id: country.id, text: country.name } 
        } ) }
      }
    }
  });
```

Routes

```
resources :users do
    resources :searches
  end
```

Searches Migrate

```
class CreateSearches < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
      t.string :country
   end
      add_index :searches, [:user_id, :created_at]

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using AJAX, for Search in country you can directly use Rails Helper Method

See the below Example :

In your `application_helper.rb` file create one method :

```
def get_country
  Country.pluck(:name,:id)
end
```

In your View file :

```
<%= f.select :country_select, get_country, {prompt: 'Select Country'} %>
```

And Lastly, add js code as follows :

```
$("#country_select").select2({
  placeholder: "Select Country"
});
```

Comment: aha ok, ill try this now. What is the benefit of using Rails Helper instead of AJAX. Why do people even use AJAX if its so complicated?

Comment: If you use rails, in this case the drop down is filled with options while it's initialization.
and AJAX is mostly used in a case when you have conditional criteria
Like, If you select country, you need states based on country selection.

If you have any JavaScript error, Then in that case your AJAX fails.

Comment: Ok so i'm now getting this error, 
undefined method `country_select' for #<Search:0x007fc7f79217d0>.  I've updates the above to also contain the migrate file of searches. I tried renaming from country_select to country and the page loaded, however the select2 just showed up as a normal drop down

Comment: Actually, The "f" is representing form object, You need to set the form according to that. If you wont have forn, You can use Rails select_tag

Comment: It's been pleasure to help.!

Answer (score 1):

As you have written the code in the **new action**, the URL you were calling is wrong,
If you want to call from new action,

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
before_action :require_user
respond_to :html, :json

    def new
        @countries = Country.all
        respond_with @countries
    end
end
```

Either change the url in the ajax call like this,

```
  $('#country_select').select2({
    theme: "bootstrap",
    ajax: {
      url: "<%= new_user_search_path(format: 'json') %>",
      dataType: "json",
      results: function(data, page) {
        return { results: $.map( data, function(country, i) { 
          return { id: country.id, text: country.name } 
        } ) }
      }
    }
  });
```

Or change the code to index action,

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
before_action :require_user
respond_to :html, :json

    def index
        @countries = Country.all
        respond_with @countries
    end
end
```

Then, you can use that url of yours,

```
  $('#country_select').select2({
    theme: "bootstrap",
    ajax: {
      url: "<%= user_searches_path(format: 'json') %>",
      dataType: "json",
      results: function(data, page) {
        return { results: $.map( data, function(country, i) { 
          return { id: country.id, text: country.name } 
        } ) }
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Hi @sravan, so after using your New action, the select box gets stuck on "searching" and I have the below error

Comment: Started GET "/users/1/searches/new.json?q=aus" for ::1 
Processing by SearchesController#new as JSON
  Parameters: {"q"=>"aus", "user_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["id", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error
ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing template searches/new, application/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.

Comment: then the method call is correct, just add new.html.erb filein views/searches

Comment: whats weird is that already have that page, the javascript is being run from the app/views/searches/new page. (new.html.erb)

Comment: k, as you have given json its searching fir a js file, add new.js.erb

Comment: great success! Thanks!

Comment: Np, you can accept my answer if it got worked for you.